# How do I reference a variable in c# unity when it is another script attached to another gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a score counter system and basically it works when the enemy gets destroyed by a barrier but because the enemy gets clone multiple times it does not work, and I need help with the issue.

```
        if (sphere.IsDestroyed() && player.IsDestroyed() == false)
        {

            int result = (score + scoreaddconfig);
            scorenumber.text = result.ToString();
        }
```

The text above is the score system and the one below is the variable I am trying to reference

```
       var position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7.08f,-2.16f), 2.87f, 29.46f);
```

I am expecting to find a way where I can reference the variables in c# and put it in another script

Comment: You say "the enemy gets cloned", but you don't explain which script this code is running on. Is it running on the enemy? Nor have you explained which script the `position` variable exists in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is running on the gameobject sphere which is where the other script exists, the one that needs to be referenced.

Comment: The position variable and everything below is in the gameobject sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest & quickest way would be to create a class using the singleton pattern to store game state information, like score. Example:

```
public sealed class DataManager
{
    private static DataManager instance = null;

    private DataManager()
    {
    }

    public static DataManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new DataManager();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then access this singleton instance with `DataManager.Instance` from anywhere in your project. For example, if you add a score variable in this DataManager class, you can access it like so: `DataManager.Instance.score`